# MediaElement doesn't play sound effect

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to play a beep sound effect when the user clicks.

I have a `beep.mp3` file added to the project (isn't in a folder). In it's properties I see `Build Action` is set to `Content`

and this MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement Name="beep" Source="beep.mp3" Volume="1" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

then I can't hear any sounds after this:

```
beep.Play();
```

Comment: maybe its just too short so you can't hear it? try with longer mp3 to make sure..

Comment: I'd suggest you consider using the `SoundEffect` class instead ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx)). The audio files must be WAV files though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've build a simple example (following your code) and everything should be ok. Just to ensure that everything is all right I'll perform some checkups described below:
In XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" VerticalAlignment="Cener" Content="BEEP"/>
<MediaElement Name="beep" Source="beep.mp3" Volume="1" AutoPlay="False" MediaFailed="beep_MediaFailed" MediaOpened="beep_MediaOpened"/>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   myButton.Click += (sender, e) => { beep.Play(); };
   // this below checks if your file exists 
   if (Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("beep.mp3", UriKind.Relative)) == null)
        MessageBox.Show("File not Exists!");
}

private void beep_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //  Show Message when opening failed 
   MessageBox.Show("There was an error: " + e.ErrorException.Message);
}

private void beep_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // as it's subscribed in xaml, juts after opening the App you should hear beep
   beep.Play();
   MessageBox.Show("Media opened");
}
```

First - in Constructor I perform a check up if my beep.mp3 exist (check if I can get it as a resource stream). If everything is ok, there you shouldn't see a message. Then after a while you should see one of the messages (Failed/Opened). If opened, then you should also hear beep.mp3.
Just be aware that if you for example put beep.Play() just after InitializeComponent, then you probably won't hear it - that's becasue the media must be opened before it's played (of course normally there is no need to subscribe to that event if you don't need to, but if you are having problems then it's nice to know if the media was opened).
On the other hand I would probably follow WiredPraire suggestion (in comment) and used `SoundEffect` to play short sounds.
Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar in Silverlight project. Try to add it into Assets folder, set to Content/Resource and Copy always to output.